# Extracting visible sheet in Revit using C#

Tags: c#, revit-api

Is there a way to only select Sheet Lists in a Schedule?

Like in this picture, but instead of those fields, I want only the existent Sheet Lists in the project.

[Creating a Sheet List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0KuY.png), but I want all the Sheet Lists in the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found code that helped me out with this:

```
public IEnumerable<ViewSheet> GetAllSheets (Document doc)
        {

            IEnumerable<ViewSheet> sheets = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
                .OfClass(typeof(ViewSheet))
                .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Sheets)
                .Cast<ViewSheet>()
                ;

            return sheets;
        }
```